# python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully while installing Quspin

Tags: python, pip

I am using Google Colaboratory, I want to install quspin. Since there is not way to install it using pip according to this tread [1](https://github.com/QuSpin/QuSpin/issues/241), I am using the GitHub repository:
`pip install git+https://github.com/weinbe58/QuSpin.git`, however; the following error appears:

```py
Collecting git+https://github.com/weinbe58/QuSpin.git
  Cloning https://github.com/weinbe58/QuSpin.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-1bwnulan
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/weinbe58/QuSpin.git /tmp/pip-req-build-1bwnulan
  Resolved https://github.com/weinbe58/QuSpin.git to commit c19e0c507b62be0fd1087c435870f2b0489c2119
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have already search and try to update pip, setuptools, etc, nothing works. I don't know if there is a bug in setup.py on the quspin repository. Any help is welcome.